# ¿Existe alguna traducción adecuada para "Habemos" en inglés?

Tags: traducción, conjugación

En español existe la conjugación del verbo *haber* «habemos» para indicar la existencia de un conjunto de personas que cumplen ciertas características e incluyen a la persona que habla, algunos ejemplos de uso:

- Habemos personas honestas.
- Habemos personas a quienes no nos gusta el beisbol.

Reescritas de formas simples sería algo como:

- Hay personas honestas, incluyendome.
- Hay personas a quienes no les gusta el beisbol, me incluyo.

¿Existe una traducción adecuada en inglés para esta palabra?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a translation from Spanish to English. Even if English is the "de facto" language of the site, leaving this question could promote the idea that we do translations "both ways". Besides, just for the title is something that belong to a different Stack. The user is just taking advantage of this site's nature to ask the question in Spanish.

Answer (score 3):

Respondiendo un poco a la pregunta, el uso de "habemos" no está recomendado en los casos expuestos en la pregunta, su uso constituye un vulgarismo.

Según - [RAE](http://www.rae.es/consultas/habemos#sthash.OQgyN4xq.dpuf)

```
Habemos
```

**usos incorrectos:**
En la lengua culta actual, la primera persona del plural del presente de indicativo del verbo haber es hemos, y no la arcaica habemos, cuyo uso en la formación de los tiempos compuestos de la conjugación es hoy un vulgarismo propio del habla popular que debe evitarse en el habla culta; así, no debe decirse Habemos visto a tu hermano, sino Hemos visto a tu hermano.
También debe evitarse en el habla culta el uso de habemos con el sentido de ‘somos o estamos’, puesto que el verbo haber, cuando se emplea para denotar la presencia o existencia de personas o cosas, es impersonal y, como tal, se usa solo en tercera persona del singular: Hay pocos solteros en el pueblo; Había tres personas en la habitación. Por lo tanto, si quien habla desea incluirse en la referencia, no debe emplear el verbo haber en primera persona del plural, como se hace a veces en el habla popular, recurriendo, para el presente de indicativo, a la forma habemos: Habemos pocos solteros en el pueblo, Habemos tres personas en la habitación; debe decirse Somos pocos solteros en el pueblo, Estamos tres personas en la habitación.

**uso correcto:**
Solo es admisible hoy en la lengua culta el uso de la forma habemos como primera persona del plural del presente de indicativo de la expresión coloquial habérselas con una persona o cosa (‘enfrentarse a ella o tratar con ella a la fuerza’): Ya sabéis con quién nos las habemos; Nos las habemos con un asesino despiadado.

Comment: Cabe añadir que, en latin, la palabra "habemus" quiere decir "tenemos".  Por ejemplo,  "habemus papam".  Esto puede dar lugar a que cierta gente insista en usar una forma incorrecta, porque suena a lo académico.

Comment: Yo no estoy tan de acuerdo con eso que consigna la RAE, ya que es un uso normal y aceptado en América el usar `habemos` para dar a entender que _existe alguien que..._ y dentro de ese _alguien_ nos incluimos. No me imagino diciendo: `Hemos personas honestas`. Suena raro y carece de ese matiz de inclusión del hablante. A menos que alguien tenga un contraejemplo o explique que recomienda la RAE me parece un uso legitimo. En cuanto a la traducción: _There are honest people. There are people who do not like baseball._ y quizá para enfatizar se podría agregar al final: _And I am one of them._

Comment: @Aradnix, ¿puedes enlazarnos algún texto en que se use esa construcción? Literario o de un periódico.

Answer (score 0):

Para tus frases con habemos, es díficil traducirlas a inglés ya que son incorrectas en español. Lo explican bien en 
http://castellanoactual.com/uso-incorrecto-de-haber-habemos/

Las frases que comienzan por "hay" son correctas y en inglés se usaría "there is" para el singular y "there are" para el plural.